# power query to return true / false if multiple columns are either = or null

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery

Here's what I am trying to do.

I need a query to figure out if a worker has moved state in the last month.

the columns I'm working with show state as a 2-digit EX: TX

the provincial move data all show in 1 column formatted as seen below:

[image]

I've tried separating the 1 column by delimiter which would give as many new columns as there are delimiters.
then tried inserting a custom column to return (true/false) if there were any changes, but no luck...

what I'd be looking for is a simple power query code that would return any and all changes as true per the example below:

if there were any changes to the 2-digit state code, it should return "True". and "False" only if there were no changes to the 2-digit state codes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, add column, custom column with formula

```
= try if List.Count(List.Distinct(Text.Split([YourColumnNameHere]," > "))) =1 then false else true otherwise true
```

[image]

In excel, something like this, which someone will add a more compact version of

```
=IFERROR(NOT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," > ",",")&",",LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," > ",",")&",",FIND(",",SUBSTITUTE(A1," > ",","))),"")=""),TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: do you mind explaining the logic behind the formulas?

i'll give this a try

Comment: which formulas? powerquery I wrote and can do, the other one I can't and is a hack job

Comment: ok, and so did it work? And which one?